# Detect an event from inside an iframe in Angular

Tags: angular

I've created an Angular Material modal that loads an Iframe. In this Iframe there is a form. **I would like to close the modal** after submitting this form but since the form HTML is created through the Iframe URL, I cannot attached actions to the submit button.

```
<h3 matDialogTitle>My Dialog</h3>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <iframe 
    width="800" 
    height="400"
    frameBorder="0"
    [src]=" url | saferesource">
  </iframe>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <!-- <button md-button matDialogClose>Close Dialog</button> -->
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

How can I close this modal after clicking on submit button within the generated HTML form?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the postMessage method on the Window object.

More info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Short example, in the iframe you can do:

```
window.parent.postMessage('close', '*');
```

And in the application hosting the iframe listen on this message:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
  if (event.data === 'close'){
      // close dialog
  }
}
```

Note that this is pseudo code and not checked on syntax and actually working functionality.

Comment: Thanks but I'm unsure to understand fully how to make it work. I guess the idea is to trigger the `postMessage` method whenever I hit the submit button within the Iframe? But how can I get this event as the submit button is inside the Iframe?

Comment: "how can I get this event as the submit button is inside the Iframe" is exactly the question I'm giving you the answer to : use the postMessage method. It allows to communicate between window objects ( iframes , popups, .. ) originating from a parent window ( your application ). Basically you just send a request from the iframe window to the hosting window the event => close the popup